# Even when a key X is specified to Git, Ubuntu keeps popping up a screen asking for another key Y's password. Why?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I'm currently running from my Java application a Git command like this:

```
bash -c GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/secret/other_key' git clone ssh_repo .
```

I'm running it with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` such that I can force Git to use a particular key, avoiding having it attempt to pick up my usual ones available in my machine.

The issue I'm facing is that for some reason, Ubuntu seems to still pop up a screen asking for my password for my personal key (not the `~/secret/other_key` I'm passing in!). If I refuse to provide the key, it still somehow does the clone correctly, but I don't understand why this is happening. It seems like it always defaults to attempt to use my default one and only afterwards will attempt to use `~/secret/other_key`?

Plus, I know that the command is actually picking the correct key, as when run in remote servers where only `other_key` is available, it seems to work fine.

Is there anything that could explain this behavior? I would really like to avoid it, as it's bothersome to always be asked about the password (this doesn't happen when I run `git` commands through the command-line, incidentally).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189845/how-do-i-disable-graphical-password-prompt-from-ssh

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari: Hi, I don't intend to disable Ubuntu's SSH password screen. I'm trying to understand why it's being invoked in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `-v` to your GIT_SSH_COMMAND:

```
bash -c GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vi ~/secret/other_key' git clone ssh_repo .
```

You will see exactly which key is actually being used.

Make sure "ssh_repo" is an actual SSH URL (`git@github.com:group/repo`, for instance)